# Automate Openshift pod rebuild on new Docker image

Tags: docker, openshift, gitlab

I have a docker container image in our intranet hosted Gitlab registry. I can manually pull the image from our OpenShift installation and run up an arbitrary number of pods successfully. If I rebuild the image locally and push to Gitlab I can trigger a pod rebuild manually from Openshift. All this is working well.

How can I trigger the pod rebuild automatically whenever I push a new image to the Gitlab registry? I don't see anywhere to place hooks between OpenShift and Gitlab and all my reading about Image Streams hasn't resulted in a successful automated deployment pipeline. The deployed versions below;

GitLab Community Edition 9.4.6 23ec1ec
Version

OpenShift Master:
v3.5.5.15
Kubernetes Master:
v1.5.2+43a9be4

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You possibly need to schedule update of image meta data.

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/managing_images.html#importing-tag-and-image-metadata

That requires that feature be enabled globally in the OpenShift cluster though.

A better option may be to push the image direct into the OpenShift internal registry. That can trigger the new deployment automatically.

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/managing_images.html#accessing-the-internal-registry

Comment: Thanks Graham, I'm still completely unclear how to actually *create* an image stream. If I use oc new-app <uri to my external docker image> I get a successful *deployment* which runs up a pod etc. But this doesn't actually create an image stream and so I cannot set a 'scheduled' policy on anything. Any attempts I have made to manually create an image stream to reference my external image have failed. Any pointers on how to do this would be great!

Comment: Running ``oc new-app`` with an image on an external registry should still create an image stream. What do you get for ``oc get is``? Also, go work through the interactive tutorial at https://learn.openshift.com/ on deploying from an image. It provides various examples and discusses image streams and how one can create one from an image before deploying it.

Comment: The question is though whether the cluster is even been configured to allow use of the scheduled checks for image updates.

Comment: oc get is
No resources found.

Comment: Only way there couldn't be an image stream is if you were creating raw resource objects for the deployment configuration and hardwiring external image registry image reference in the deployment configuration. So if you did that and passed the raw object definitions to 'oc create'. If using 'oc new-app image' it should create an image stream. You can confirm what it would create using the '--dry-run -o json' option to see.

Comment: @slowko I am going through similar issue. Did you figure out how? Thansk!